# how to modify dataframe values using filter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to modify some cells' values by multiplying by 10 . and it doesn't work.
Here is a simple code example: Thank you so much for help

```
a={'name':['john','eric','kate'],'buy':[100,50,200],'sell':[20,30,40]}
df=pd.DataFrame(a)
df

    name    buy sell
0   john    100 20
1   eric    50  30
2   kate    200 40

df[df['name']=='eric'].iloc[:,2:]=df[df['name']=='eric'].iloc[:,2:]*10
df

name    buy sell
0   john    100 20
1   eric    50  30
2   kate    200 40
```

but if I do this by modifying all the row values, then it is fine, so what is the problem of above code when using row filtering?  Thank you so much for your help

```
df.iloc[:,2:]=df.iloc[:,2:]*10
df

name    buy sell
0   john    100 200
1   eric    50  300
2   kate    200 400
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try

```
df.loc[df['name']=='eric',['buy','sell']] *=10
```

How it works

`.iloc` is an integer accessor. it accesses by referencing columns using their integer axis. So `df.iloc[:,2:]` is a selection of the second column index which is sell

You can achieve the same  using

```
df.iloc[df[df['name']=='eric'].index,2] *=10
```

Comment: Thanks wwnde, can I use column number instead of column name? since in my working code, I have a 100 columns, that is why I just use iloc[2:]. Thanks for help

Comment: Yes, do you mean `df.iloc[df[df['name']=='eric'].index,2] *=10`?

Comment: wow, you save me my whole night, I am sittting here for 4 hours now it is solved. It is my first time know I can use df[df['name']=='eric'].index. I learnt it hard today. Thank you! I really appreciate it. I am so happy now! Have a great night!

Comment: wwnde, I appreciate it.  But I still don't understand why my previous approach is not working by doing df[df['name']=='eric'].iloc[:,2:]=df[df['name']=='eric'].iloc[:,2:]*10

Comment: Lets do some tests `type(df[df['name']=='eric'].iloc[:,2:])` is a dataframe. Meaning, this command create a new dataframe that you end up updating. You do not update the original df. Makes sense? On the other hand, `type(df.iloc[df[df['name']=='eric'].index,2])' creates a series meaning you are subsetting and then updating

Comment: type(df.iloc[df[df['name']=='eric'].index,2:]) is also a dataframe and it still works, I don't think this is the reason?